# How to use Orderby for creating dynamic linq queries?

Tags: c#, linq

I have linq query which is as follows

```
string sortby="Date"; //it can be name or something else as well

var query=(from t in Uow.Transactions.GetAllWithReferences()
           orderby t.Date descending
           select t);
```

But I want to orderby differently based on sortby variable value. How can i do that using Linq?

Comment: consider this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby/233505#233505

Comment: here is a good link that would probably give you a better understanding on how to use the `from` clause. since you basically stated that it can be anything perhaps you need to look at the section that talks about the `Where` clause http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/CSharp3-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sample class:

```
private class Tst
{
    public int field1 { get; set; }

    public string field2 { get; set; }

    public string field3 { get; set; }
}
```

You can do it this way:

```
var index = 1;

var sortedList = (from l in list
                  orderby index == 1 ? l.field1.ToString() : index == 2 ? l.field2 : l.field3  
                  select l);
```

But as fields have different types you have to do some type cast as you see `l.field1.ToString()`

Way you do it using lambda is:

```
var sortedList =
    list.OrderBy(l => 
            index == 1 ? l.field1.ToString() 
            : index == 2 ? l.field2 
            : l.field3)
        .Select(l => l).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using reflection:

```
string sortby="Date" //it can be name or something else as well

var query=(from t in Uow.Transactions.GetAllWithReferences()
           orderby t.GetType().GetProperty(sortby).GetValue(t, null) descending
           select t);
```

Comment: I tried this but after doing this when u try to do query.tolist() it crash. Any idea y ?

Comment: I tested this querying a simple IEnumerable<T>.  If you are using the Entity Framework, you can't use reflection like this inside those queries.  See this post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546463/help-with-linq-and-generics-using-getvalue-inside-a-query

Answer (score 1):

If you use the OrderBy() LINQ extension method, you can pass in a predicate which could be something like (untested):

```
Predicate orderByClause;
if ( blah == "date" )
    orderByClause = { order => order.Date };

if ( blah == "something else" ) 
    orderByClause = { order => order.SomethingElse };

var oSortedList = oResultList.OrderBy( orderByClause );
```

I'm sure the syntax if way off, but I have done something like this before...

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library for that, here is one of my favorite : http://dynamite.codeplex.com/