# Selecting specific columns with Linq, using string or propertyInfo

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am rebuilding our reporting system using EF, where as our old system used a lot of dynamic SQL (bad i know), so i would like to do it using Linq, so it uses parameterized queries etc.

In a report a user can choose which columns of data they want to view.  Now how can i take these values and return an SQL statement using Linq and get the columns i need?  I wonder if i should even bother and just return all the data, then just show the columns the user wants on screen, which may be want i need to do, but thought i would ask anyway.

So lets take the following Linq example, i say i would only like the Id, Name and Town, how could i do this.  Currently i have something similar to

```
var columns = new List<string>() { "Id", "Name", "Town" };

return _context.Data
    .Where(e => e.Name == "test")
    .ToList();
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: This might give you an idea http://tomasp.net/blog/dynamic-linq-queries.aspx/

Answer (score 1):

if you yant select propertys accordance their names try [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library) library:

```
public List<Data> ListByNames(string[] arr)
{
    var str = string.Format("new ({0})", string.Join(", ", arr));
    return _context.Data.Select(str);
}
```

Or write your own `Expression`, see @TomBrothers answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4546633/1271037

Answer (score -1):

I know this kind of problem. Chief problem: with EF you are not handling columns any more but properties.

Try somthing like this:

```
var column="yourcolumn";
return _context.Data.Where(e => e.GetType().GetProperty(column).GetValue(_context, null)).ToList();
```

Comment: You can not use `Reflection` in the `EF` expression.

Comment: Yes you can, once you use the model instead of the context. I am using reflection myself directly on an EF model.

Comment: Means intead of returning _context.Data... you probably have to first set a var data=_context.Data, then var result=data.Where(...), then return result.

Comment: right, its possible in LINQ2OBJECT. but the question is how avoid unnecessary result form DB-query (LinqToEntity).